# error: undefined reference to cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader

Tags: c++, opencv, nvidia

### My Environment Info

- OpenCV 4.3.0
- Ubuntu 18.04
- CUDA-10.2
- [NVIDIA Video Codec SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) downloaded and headers and libs included the usr/local/cuda

**I installed OpenCV with the cmake:**

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
         -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
         -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
         -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
         -D WITH_TBB=ON \
     -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
         -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN="7.5" \
     -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=ON \
         -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
         -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
         -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
         -D BUILD_opencv_java=OFF \
         -D BUILD_ZLIB=ON \
         -D BUILD_TIFF=ON \
         -D WITH_GTK=ON \
         -D WITH_NVCUVID=ON \
         -D CUDA_nvcuvid_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvcuvid.so \
         -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
         -D WITH_1394=ON \
         -D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include \
         -D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.7.6.5 \
         -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
         -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc \
         -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv4.pc \
         -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
         -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
         -D WITH_V4L=ON \
         -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=$cwd/OpenCV-4.3.0-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
         -D WITH_QT=ON \
         -D WITH_CUDNN=ON \ON \
         -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5 \
         -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
         -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
         -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..ON \
         -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5 \
         -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
         -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
         -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

**output of cuda part:**

```
--   NVIDIA CUDA:                   YES (ver 10.2, CUFFT CUBLAS NVCUVID FAST_MATH)
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             75
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
-- 
--   cuDNN:                         YES (ver 7.6.5)
```

I installed OpenCV and tried a simple example like below and worked fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include "bits/time.h"
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>
#define TestCUDA true

int main() {
    std::clock_t begin = std::clock();

        try {
            cv::String filename = "/img/dir/1.png";
            cv::Mat srcHost = cv::imread(filename, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

            for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
                if(TestCUDA) {
                    cv::cuda::GpuMat dst, src;
                    src.upload(srcHost);

                    //cv::cuda::threshold(src,dst,128.0,255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
                    cv::cuda::bilateralFilter(src,dst,3,1,1);

                    cv::Mat resultHost;
                    dst.download(resultHost);
                } else {
                    cv::Mat dst;
                    cv::bilateralFilter(srcHost,dst,3,1,1);
                }
            }

            cv::imshow("Result",srcHost);
            cv::waitKey();

        } catch(const cv::Exception& ex) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
        }

    std::clock_t end = std::clock();
    std::cout << double(end-begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC  << std::endl;
}
```

**But when I tried to compile the code below:**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudacodec.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const std::string fname = "/video/directory/video.mp4";

    cv::namedWindow("GPU", cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);

    cv::cuda::GpuMat d_frame;
    cv::Ptr<cv::cudacodec::VideoReader> d_reader = cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader(fname);

    for (;;)
    {

        if (!d_reader->nextFrame(d_frame))
            break;

        cv::Mat frame;
        d_frame.download(frame);
        cv::imshow("GPU", frame);

        if (cv::waitKey(3) > 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It gives error on the `VideoReader` class of `cudacodec`:

> .../main.cpp:14: error: undefined reference to
> `cv::cudacodec::createVideoReader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'

**What I am missing here ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding `cmake` list the argument:

```
-D CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-10.2 \
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of your #include likely matters. Reverse the order of

```
#include <opencv2/cudacodec.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

to be the same as in the first example.